# Create new local variable via debug library?

Tags: debugging, lua, scope

You can set the value of an existing local variable via `debug.setlocal` but how would you create a new one?

Comment: Don't think you can. Why would you want to, anyway?

Comment: How would you use that new local variable?  You can not use it from your code (as all references to non-existing local variables have already been mapped to upvalues or global variables)

Comment: @egor I need it for a proof of concept, I need to create a local variable in the scope a function was called from. Is there another way to do this?

Comment: Do you want to create a new local variable at run-time and never use it in your program?  Stop wasting your time on such a pointless tasks and try to start creating something really useful.

Comment: Local variable is just a reserved place in the stack.  You can not create new one as stack locations usage is hardwired in bytecode (yes, you have to modify function's bytecode to add new local variable).

Comment: Well that's annoying. And no, the variables would be used lol.

Comment: HOW could you use local variables that was not exist at the moment of compiling the bytecode?

Comment: @egor The idea was to set up an __index and __newindex metamethod to the _G table, to index/set a local variable in the current scope. To simulate locals by default.

Comment: Will this be somewhat different from using separate environment (not equal to `_G`)?

Comment: @egor What do you mean?

Answer (score 1):

You can't create a new local variable this way. [setlocal](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#pdf-debug.setlocal) "assigns the value value to the local variable with index local of the function at level level of the stack" and "returns nil if there is no local variable with the given index", so it won't create a new variable.

Comment: I am aware of this, I want a way to create a new variable via the debug library

Comment: There is no way to do this using the debug library. As Egor said in the comment, you can probably tweak the bytecode, but it's not going to be much different from using that variable in the first place.